# What does a variable before a foreach loop mean when enclosed in square brackets (PySpark)

Tags: python, pyspark

I am still at the initial phases of learning pyspark, and I found below code confusing. Can 
 someone, please explain this to me

```
     Code  :    
    zipsSchema = smartphoneDF.schema
    print(type(zipsSchema))
    [**field** for field in zipsSchema]

  What does "field" before "for"  mean, and why is the entire statement enclosed in "[]" When I try to write the same 

    My code is as follows :

 zipsSchema = smartphoneDF.schema
    print(type(zipsSchema))
   for field in zipsSchema 
     print(field)
```

Answer (score 1):

**`field`** is an element from the **zipsSchema** struct type.

Rather than creating empty list and addint elements to the list we can write for loop in single line using `[field for field in zipsSchema]` is [list comprehension](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/) in python.

**`Example:`**

```
smartphoneDF=spark.createDataFrame([("1","a")],["id","name"])

zipsSchema=smartphoneDF.schema

fields_lc=[field for field in zipsSchema]
#[StructField(id,StringType,true), StructField(name,StringType,true)]

fields_fl=[]

for field in zipsSchema:
    fields_fl.append(field)

fields_fl
#[StructField(id,StringType,true), StructField(name,StringType,true)]
```

As you can see `fields_lc`, `fields_fl` values are same and creation is different.